# CSS/DIV question - Scrollbar moves, but content does not

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, sidenav

Context: Wordpress, custom page
Situation: I open a sidepanel with more info when user clicks on a 'Read more' in the page.

Problem: The sidepanel appears with a scrollbar, but moving the scroll bar does nothing. That is, the content does not move.

Please see: https://www.staging11.primeinvestor.in/prime-etfs/

(Please click on the third 'Read more' link)

Appreciate the help!

thanks,

Srikanth

My CSS is:

```
   .sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff7f4;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 130px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #35080c;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  .sidenav p {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #35080c;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .sidenav a:hover {
    color: #dc4b00;
  }

  .sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 100px;

  }

  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .sidenav .closebtn {
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 16px
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `position: fixed;` to make your element scrollable. `fixed` positions will make your element stick right where it is even if scrollbar is working. Instead, use

```
.sidenav {
    ....
    position: relative; // change your code here
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    ....
  }
```

Comment: Kirubel, m3, thank you. However, if I change it to 'relative' ,the side panel does not appear at all when I click 'Read more'. I use         elem.style.width = "300px"; to open the sidepanel onClick(). Thanks!

Comment: @SrikanthMeenakshi in that case you might need to add an extra `div` element to wrap all the content and make it scrollable. If you provide your `HTML` it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually, when I do position relative, all the divs appear on top of the main content in the page (in one single thin width=0 ). Just noticed. Anyways, I have .a set of divs in the page - one for each 'read more'. Their parent div is just the body of the page.

Comment: I have updated the URL above with the position relative. You can see it now and 'view source' to see the html...thanks!

Comment: @SrikanthMeenakshi why did you set the `width: 0;`?

Comment: I agree that this is the solution, but not directly usable for me - more an artifact of my situation than the generic problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, Kirubel, just seeing your message - set the width to 0 so I can open/close it at click of the link. Should I set it to wrapper div to the width of the panel? I'll try that and see...

Comment: That did not seem to work either - I'll look for work-arounds rather than a direct solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're using positon: fixed on the sidenav.
The fixed attributes sticks the div on its view port position without the ability to scroll it away